# How do i read a text file on any computer instead of from a drive?

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files, filepath

I currently use the following to find the file

```
    String file_path1 = "E:/Customers.txt";
    String file_path2 = "E:/Events.txt";
```

This works fine however as i am using a different computer in a different location can i change this so that it will find the file no matter what computer I am on. I have tried moving the file about inside the folder that contains the program and changing my code to

```
    String file_path1 = "src:/Customers.txt";
    String file_path2 = "src:/Events.txt";
```

But i still get a no file found error

What can i change this to so i stop having to change the drive letter everytime it is opened on a new computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put a colon (**:**) in relative paths:
Use this:

```
String file_path1 = "src/Customers.txt";
String file_path2 = "src/Events.txt";
```

Comment: @user3620639 Kindly mark this as an answer by clicking the tick button. :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess,you need to change to

```
String file_path1 = "src:/Customers.txt";
```

to:

```
String src_path = "****"; //Use utils or ClassLoader get real path
String file_path1 = src_path + "/Customers.txt";
```